# CheckedListBox Selected Items to SQL

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way to get list of selected items from CheckedListBox to use it in SQL expression? I got `CheckedListBox` filled with columns name `(.DisplayMember = "COLUMN_NAME", .ValueMember = "COLUMN_NAME")` and want user to select only the columns he wants to export to Excel.  I just need that he selected for example `Name, ID, Number` to use it like `SELECT Name, ID, Number FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
 If CheckedListBox.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
     Dim columns = String.Join(",", CheckedListBox.CheckedItems.Cast(Of String))

     Dim query = String.Format("SELECT {0} FROM ..", columns)
     'Proceed
  Else
     'Prompt user to select columns
  End If
```